MacOS [NSProcessInfo processInfo] on Sequoia broken?
For years I have determined the operating system version with:
NSOperatingSystemVersion ver = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];

(My code runs as a plugin inside SketchUp)
With Sequoia, if I run this code inside SketchUp 2020, it returns:
10,16  (??)
If I run my code inside SketchUp 2024, this returns:
15,0  (as expected)
How can the App in which the code is running change the operating system version?

This question is similar to: Troubles getting an actual macOS version. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Oh, nice!  Thanks you.  But Oh Apple, where did you go so wrong..
